# Float images left (have them side by side) and vertically centered, then drop below centered

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to Float images left (have them side by side) and vertically center them in the div, then have them stack vertically while keeping them horizontally centered in the div when the window is resized. 
I have it so that it is horizontally centered, and stays that way, I just can't figure out how to vertically center it.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my html:

```css
.mainContainer {
 max-width:90%;
 background-color: #00a5bd;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 0 !important;
 min-height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Working HTML</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/273x138"></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x138"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want the two to be vertical in the left?

Comment: @DanyCode, I actually need them to stay right in the middle. If the two images are side by side they will both be on the same line but within the center of the container div, but if it is resized, I would like them to have one drop one below the other, and both be centered.... If that makes any sense lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution where the .flex-item elements are 'display: inline-block' and 'vertical-align: middle'.  you'll also need the .flex-container to have 'text-align: center' if you want them centered.  I added an inline height for proof of concept.

```css
.mainContainer {
 max-width:90%;
 background-color: #00a5bd;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 0 !important;
 min-height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Working HTML</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/273x138"></li>
  <li class="flex-item" style="height: 110px"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x138" height="100"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is extremely close, I just would like to have the two flex-containers centered within the mainContainer..

Comment: this link may help: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/  I have a feeling you'll have to work with position: absolute if you're wanting it centered on the screen.  Or possibly play around with inline-block and vertical-align: middle some more.  Good luck!

Comment: That was the perfect resource, and I got it working in no time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you need to add the min height to flex-container and add align-items: center :)

Answer (score 0):

is it this way you want them to be?

```css
.mainContainer {
 max-width:90%;
 background-color: #00a5bd;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 0 !important;
 min-height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/273x138"></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x138"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```